# ClassNotFoundException found while loading classes from extension classloader using java

Tags: java, command, classloader, processbuilder

I am using processbuilder to run specific task in seperate JVM instance. i have two directory `lib` and `conflictlib`. `lib` directory i have added under classpath and `conflictlib` i have added in `"java.ext.dirs"` System property. `

here is my command:

```
java -Xmx64m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dserver.home='/home/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF' -Djava.ext.dirs='/home/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/conflictlib' -cp  '/home/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib' SubProcessClass
```

why i have added `conflictlib` in `java.ext.dirs` system property-

i have some conflict jar files(same jar with different version) in `lib` and `conflictlib`. Task i need to perform in subprocess, classes should be loaded from `conflictlib` directory. `lib` directory i have added under -cp which will be loaded by System class loader and `conflictlib` is loaded by extension classloader. since extension class loaded first. but I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONArray
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

json-20140107.jar
```

present under `conflictlib` directory. its giving `ClassNotFoundException`. could someone check this. i am not able to understand where i am doing mistake.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Java version? `java.ext.dirs` afaik ceased being a thing at version 8. If you're using a higher version, you're going to need to extend to the classpath

Comment: @g00se java 8 version

Comment: @g00se till java 8 version. it wont support ?

Comment: The opposite. So that's not your problem. You can't, in a normal app, use a directory classpath for jars, so each jar in WEB-INF/lib you will need to list separately. Any other jar elsewhere also should be listed separately